# Set the starting point of a horizontal UIScrollView

Tags: ios, xcode4, uiscrollview

I've tried many different solutions but none of them are working for me..

I have a horizontal scroll view, now it starts at the left, but how can i make it start at the middle?

I'm using this code right now in the Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [scroller2 setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [scroller2 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1735, 300)];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

and
`IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroller2;` in the header file.

I'd made the content in interface builder (.xib file), and i'm using Xcode 4.2!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to call [`scrollRectToVisible:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIScrollView/scrollRectToVisible%3aanimated%3a)

try this in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` or sth. similar.

```
 [scroller2 scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(1735/2.0, 300/2.0, 1,1) animated:NO]
```

Comment: There are no errors given, But what do i need to change for the starting point?

Comment: ^^ I dont understand. my solution just makes the middlemost pixel inside your scrollview visible.

Comment: maybe we understand sth different with "starting point". I understand a scrollview which is initially scrolled to the middle and Deepak understands shifted content inside the scrollview

Comment: This worked for me!! Thanks a lot!! I just changed the 1,1 to 560,560 it just opens in the middle! I Don't know if this is the "official" way, but it works. Thanks!!

Comment: @thomas There wasn't a misunderstanding. Both of us solved the same issue. Setting `contentInset` would shift the content inside the scrollview whereas `contentOffset` tells us where the origin of the scroll view lies within the content view. When you use `scrollRectToVisible:`, `contentOffset` changes too.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the `contentOffset` property.

```
[scroller2 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(appropriateXDisplacement, 0)];
```

Comment: +1 agreed, change the content offest to position the content within the UIScrollView

Comment: Should i add this code just under the `[scroller2 setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1735, 300)];`  line? Because when i do this, i'm getting a error.. "Use of undeclared identifier 'appropriateXDisplacement'"

Comment: `appropriateXDisplacement` is just a suggestion. Replace it with a value you want to move to

Comment: Suppose the width of the scroll view is 320. Then it will be 1735/2.0 - 160 i.e. 707.5 should be the value I guess